# Disable english dictionnary in emacs predictive mode latex

Tags: dictionary, emacs, latex, emacs24

I was trying to edit my LaTeX document on Emacs and found out about predictive-mode but here is my problem.

I want predictive-mode to work only on keywords (usually starting with \ but it can be itemize in \begin{itemize}) but it keeps loading the english dictionnary whenever I start it. So my .emacs file looks like that

```
;; predictive install location

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/predictive/")
;; dictionary locations
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/predictive/latex/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/predictive/texinfo/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/predictive/html/")

;; load predictive package
(autoload 'predictive-mode "~/.emacs.d/predictive/predictive"
  "Turn on Predictive Completion Mode." t)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'predictive-mode)

(setq predictive-main-dict 'dict-latex)
```

As you can see I ask Emacs to set the default dictionnary to `dict-latex` but is it the right solution since there are a lot of LaTeX dictionaries ?

The fact is I'm not really good with Lisp and don't understand what to do. For example, in [the predictive-mode manuual](http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/predictive-user-manual/html/Parsing-LaTeX-Documents.html#Parsing-LaTeX-Documents) it is said

> By default, predictive mode will use the usual main dictionary in LaTeX mode, determined by predictive-main-dict (see Basic Dictionary Usage). However, by customizing predictive-latex-docclass-alist, the main dictionary can be selected automatically based on the document class.

But I don't understand if this can solve my problem and if yes how to do it.

Thanks in advance for all the answers and sorry if I made some english errors :)

Lhooq